# How to give a size to a square matrix in a class

Tags: c++, class, matrix

I need to give a size to the matrix inside the class, but with a `const int size` the compiler complain. There is an elegant way to meet my needs?

*header.h*

```
class ChessBoard {
    int matrix[<size>][<size>];
public:
    ChessBoard(int s): <size>(s) {}
};
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter the size of the chessboard: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    ChessBoard cb(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant create array like this, wihtout knowing the size in compile time. Create array using pointers and new. Working with this kid of array will be the same as with [][]. Only difference will be, that you need to delete your allocated array, first one will be deleted "automaticly".

```
int ** matrix = new int*[s];
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) 
{
   matrix[i] = new int[s];
}
```

And at the end `delete[]` array from memory

```
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) 
{
  delete[] matrix[i];
}
delete[] matrix;
```

Comment: So.. in the first example the line 1 initialize a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-array, and the for creates a new array of size `s` inside each box of the `matrix` array?

Answer (score 2):

In order to instantiate a fixed size matrix, the dimensions need to be compile time constants. In your case, the size is determined at runtime. I suggest using an `std::vector<int>`, and giving two-index access if necessary. A 2D structure just adds unnecessary complexity:

```
class ChessBoard 
{
  std::vector<int> matrix;
public:
  int& operator()(size_t row, size_t column) { /* get element from matrix*/ }
  constint& operator()(size_t row, size_t column) const { /* get element from matrix*/ }
  ChessBoard(int s): matrix(s) {}
};
```